# C# Rabbitmq Producer

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am trying to experiment with rabbitmq to implement it into my project but I am a bit confused while reading some recommendations on how I should use a queue.
Based on https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/part4-rabbitmq-13-common-errors.html they were recommending that I should not open and close connections or channels repeatedly. However, now my implementation there is 1 exchange with 3 queue I created something more dynamic where I accept the message and routing key and then create a connection to send to the respective queue.

Is there a better approach to this to counter the recommendation that I should not open and close connections or channels repeatedly?

```
 public void SendMessageQueue(string message, string routingKey)
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
                connectionFactory.HostName = configuration["RabbitMQ:HostName"];
                connectionFactory.UserName = configuration["RabbitMQ:Username"];
                connectionFactory.Password = configuration["RabbitMQ:Password"];

                IConnection connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
                IModel channel = connection.CreateModel();
                IBasicProperties properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                properties.Persistent = true;

                byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: configuration["RabbitMQ:Exchange"],
                          routingKey: routingKey,
                          basicProperties: properties,
                          body: body);

                channel.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageUtil.Error("SendMessageQueue, error running the code.", ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can add them as static objects, so that you can save it and reuse for later

Comment: I strongly recommend using a framework like Rebus or MassTransit that focuses on what you do and not how. Both are wrappers over Rabbit.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks for the information let me try them out and share it here again! :D

Comment: @rosepalette: Even if you want to go low level and make rabbit connections on your own, still pay attention to both frameworks - just read their sources and learn how they manage rabbit connections. We've been using MT for years and switched to Rebus like two years ago in a busy system ( up to 1000 msg/sec), no serious issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not recommended to open and close connections repeatly on RabbitMQ is because it stresses the machine, so you really should avoid doing that, a workaround for this recommendation is to initialize the ConnectionFactory in the constructor and use a Singleton for the IConnection interface, this way you avoid creating N connections but you keep the N channels which is not enforced but also not discouraged.

It would be like this

```
public class YourClass 
{
    private readonly ConnectionFactory _factory;
    private IConnection _connection;
    
    public YourClass(string connectionString)
    {
       _factory = new ConnectionFactory
       {
          Uri = new Uri(connectionString),
          DispatchConsumersAsunc = true,
          AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
       };
    }

    public void Send(string message, string routingKey)
    {
       if(_connection == null || !_connection.IsOpen) _connection = _factory.CreateConnection(YourConnectionName);
       IModel channel = _connection.CreateModel();
       IBasicProperties properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
       properties.Persistent = true;

       byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

       channel.BasicPublish(exchange: configuration["RabbitMQ:Exchange"],
                      routingKey: routingKey,
                      basicProperties: properties,
                      body: body);
       channel.Close();
    }
}
```